# Why does Flask-Security Cause a new KVSession Record for Each Request?

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-security, flask-kvsession

I'm trying out using [Flask-KVSession](http://flask-kvsession.readthedocs.org/) as an alternative session implementation for a Flask web site. I've created a test website (see **Code 1** below). When I run this, I can use the browser to store values into the session by navigating between the various resources in my web browser. This works correctly. Also, when I look at the `sessions` table in the resulting SQLite database, I see a single record that was being used to store this session the entire time.

Then I try to add [Flask-Security](http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Security/) to this (see **Code 2** below). After running this site (making sure to first delete the existing test.db sqlite file), I am brought to the login prompt and I log in. Then I proceed to do the same thing of jumping back and forth between the resources. I get the same results.

The problem is that when I look in the sqlitebrowser `sessions` table, there are 8 records. It turns out a new session record was created for EACH request that was made.

Why does a new session record get created for each request when using Flask-Security? Why isn't the existing session updated like it was before?

**Code 1 (KVSession without Flask-Security)**

```
import os
from flask import Flask, session

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = os.urandom(64)
#############
# SQLAlchemy
#############
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
DB_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
DB_URI = 'sqlite:////{0}/test.db'.format(DB_DIR)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = DB_URI

@app.before_first_request
def create_user():
    db.create_all()

############
# KVSession
############
from simplekv.db.sql import SQLAlchemyStore
from flask.ext.kvsession import KVSessionExtension
store = SQLAlchemyStore(db.engine, db.metadata, 'sessions')
kvsession = KVSessionExtension(store, app)

@app.route('/a')
def a():
    session['last'] = 'b'
    return 'Thank you for visiting A!'

@app.route('/b')
def b():
    session['last'] = 'b'
    return 'Thank you for visiting B!'

@app.route('/c')
def c():
    return 'You last visited "{0}"'.format(session['last'])


app.run(debug=True)
```

**Code 2 (KVSession WITH Flask-Security)**

```
import os
from flask import Flask, session

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = os.urandom(64)
#############
# SQLAlchemy
#############
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
DB_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
DB_URI = 'sqlite:////{0}/test.db'.format(DB_DIR)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = DB_URI

###########
# Security
###########
# This import needs to happen after SQLAlchemy db is created above
from flask.ext.security import (
    Security, SQLAlchemyUserDatastore, current_user,
    UserMixin, RoleMixin, login_required
)

# Define models
roles_users = db.Table('roles_users',
        db.Column('user_id', db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('user.id')),
        db.Column('role_id', db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('role.id')))

class Role(db.Model, RoleMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
    description = db.Column(db.String(255))

class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(255))
    active = db.Column(db.Boolean())
    confirmed_at = db.Column(db.DateTime())
    roles = db.relationship('Role', secondary=roles_users,
                            backref=db.backref('users', lazy='dynamic'))

user_datastore = SQLAlchemyUserDatastore(db, User, Role)
security = Security(app, user_datastore)

@app.before_first_request
def create_user():
    db.create_all()
    user_datastore.create_user(email='test@example.com', password='password')
    db.session.commit()


############
# KVSession
############
from simplekv.db.sql import SQLAlchemyStore
from flask.ext.kvsession import KVSessionExtension
store = SQLAlchemyStore(db.engine, db.metadata, 'sessions')
kvsession = KVSessionExtension(store, app)

@app.route('/a')
@login_required
def a():
    session['last'] = 'b'
    return 'Thank you for visiting A!'

@app.route('/b')
@login_required
def b():
    session['last'] = 'b'
    return 'Thank you for visiting B!'

@app.route('/c')
@login_required
def c():
    return 'You last visited "{0}"'.format(session['last'])


app.run(debug=True)
```

**Version Info**

```
Python 2.7.3
Flask==0.9
Flask==0.9
Flask-KVSession==0.3.2
Flask-Login==0.1.3
Flask-Mail==0.8.2
Flask-Principal==0.3.5
Flask-SQLAlchemy==0.16
Flask-Security==1.6.3
SQLAlchemy==0.8.1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out this is related to a [known problem](https://github.com/maxcountryman/flask-login/pull/24) with [flask-login](https://flask-login.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) (which flask-security uses) when flask-login is used with a session storage library like KVSession.

Basically, KVSession needs to update the database with the new session information whenever data in the session is created or modified. And in the sample above, this happens correctly: the first time I hit a page, the session is created. After that, the existing session is updated.

However, in the background the browser sends a cookie-less request to my web server looking for my favicon. Therefore, flask is handling a request to `/favicon.ico`. This request (or any other request that would 404) is still handled by flask. This means that flask-login will look at the request and try to do its magic.

It so happens that flask-login doesn't TRY to put anything into the session, but it still LOOKS like the session has been modified as far as KVSession is concerned. Because it LOOKS like the session is modified, KVSession updates the database. The following is code from flask-login:

```
def _update_remember_cookie(self, response):
    operation = session.pop("remember", None)
    ...
```

The `_update_remember_cookie` method is called during the request lifecycle. Although session.pop will not change the session if the session doesn't have the "remember" key (which in this case it doesn't), KVSession still sees a pop and assumes that the session changes.

The issue for flask-login provides the simple bug fix, but it has not been pushed into flask-login. It appears that the maintainer is looking for a complete rewrite, and will implement it there.